# Swift game error message

Tags: swift

I am following an iOS game tutorial. I cannot figure out what is wrong here. 
Error is on these two lines.

```
  let newAngle = percent * 180 - 180
  cannon.zRotation = CGFloat(newAngle) * CGFloat(M_PI); 180.0

  //error is "use of unresolved identifier 'percent'"
```

The tutorial uses:

```
  cannon.zRotation = CGFloat(newAngle) * CGFloat(M_PI)/ 180.0
```

but I changed it as error suggested

---

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var cannon: SKSpriteNode!
    var touchLocation:CGPoint = CGPointZero


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
         cannon = self.childNodeWithName("cannon") as! SKSpriteNode

    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */
        touchLocation = touches.first!.locationInNode(self)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        touchLocation = touches.first!.locationInNode(self)

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
         let precent = touchLocation.x / size.width
         let newAngle = percent * 180 - 180
         cannon.zRotation = CGFloat(newAngle) *; CGFloat(M_PI); 180.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You declare a constant as `let precent` but then attempt to use `percent`. Check your spelling carefully.

Comment: so stupid. ;;;; thanks : )